# Why can I not use re.sub to replace a group?

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to find a group in a string using `regex` and replace it with a space.

The group I am looking to find is a group of symbols only when they fall between strings. When I use `re.findall()` it works exactly as expected

```
word = 'This##Is # A # Test#'
print(word)
re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z\s]*([\$\#\%\!\s]*)[a-zA-Z]",word)
>>> ['##', '# ', '# ', '']
```

But when I use `re.sub()`, instead of replacing the group, it replaces the entire regex.

```
x = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z\s]*([\$\#\%\!\s]*)[a-zA-Z]",r' ',word)
print(x)
>>> '    #'
```

How can I use regular expressions to replace ONLY the group? The outcome I expect is:

```
'This Is A Test#'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, there's no need to escape every "magic" character within a character class, `[$#%!\s]*` is equally fine and much more readable.
2. Second, *matching* (i.e. retrieving) is different from *replacing* and you could use backreferences to achieve your goal.
3. Third, if you only want to have `#` at the end, you could help yourself with a much easier expression:

   ```
   (?:[\s#](?!\Z))+
   ```

   Which would then need to be replaced by a space, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pj52c5/1/).

   ---

   In `Python` this could be:

   ```
   import re

   string = "This##Is # A # Test#"
   rx = re.compile(r'(?:[\s#](?!\Z))+')

   new_string = rx.sub(' ', string)
   print(new_string)
   # This Is A Test#
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the portions of the pattern you want to retain and use backreferences in your replacement string instead:

```
x = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z\s]*)[\$\#\%\!\s]*([a-zA-Z])", r'\1 \2', word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regex matches the wrong thing entirely.

```py
x = re.sub(r'\b[$#%!\s]+\b', ' ', word)
```